# Copy-protecting files on an HDD

Tags: file-management, file-permissions, read-only, copy-protection

I have an HDD, with files that I don't want to be "stolen".

The HDD is used by my employees. They need the files (pdf-s, some portable program and html files) for their work, but I don't want them to copy some of it to a pendrive or anywhere. What are my options? I can't disable copy on an HDD...

Comment: External HDD? Internal HDD? If it's internal, you can use a soldering iron to disable the USB ports. Combined with full disk encryption, this will make it pretty hard to copy the files. But don't forget: physical access is root access. You can only make it harder, not impossible.

Comment: External HDD. :(

Comment: You'll never get an absolute solution for this. For example, even if your staff can open a PDF or the HTML file, what's going to stop them from hitting "Print Screen" to take a snap shot of the page if they can't save the original file? You could use Group Policy (if you use a Windows domain) to prevent USB drives being inserted that don't have the same UIDs as the ones you provide them.

Comment: A TrueCrypt like software with an user management plugin would be enough. If there is one.

Comment: You could make your employees sign an agreement...

Comment: If you can read it, you can copy it. The end. :)

Comment: (Unanswered) Dupe: [Prevent copying from specific network locations](http://superuser.com/questions/587269/prevent-copying-from-specific-network-locations?rq=1), another one: [How to prevent file copy, restricted by file size?](http://superuser.com/questions/568280/how-to-prevent-file-copy-restricted-by-file-size?rq=1)

Comment: The answer to this question comes from the HR department, not IT.